# How to find the variance of stochastic integration

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm studying Stochastic Calculus and I'm stuck in the problem :
$E\int_{0}^{T}(e^{tB_t})^2dt$ where $B_t$ is Brownian Motion.
How can I find that expectation?

Comment: Common beginner tips: Please include your work on the problem. The question is quite short which means that people may be want to write mediocre answers unless you improve the question. [Some help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: It is $\int_0^{T} Ee^{2tB_t}dt=\int_0^{T} e^{2t^{3}} dt$